# Prepend to all rows of textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea, prepend

I have this little text area in a page, that I wish to simply prepend ">>" to each line.

I thought it might be as simple as:

```
   $("#mytextarea").prepend("EvilHacker001>>");
```

But that didn't do anything.  I've looked around and I couldn't find anything like foreach('line') relating to textarea.

Is there an easy way to do this??  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each line:

```
$('textarea').val(function(_, value){
   var arr = value.split('\n');
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        arr[i] = "EvilHacker001>>" + arr[i];
   return arr.join('\n');     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DpQS4/

For each value:

```
$('textarea').val(function(_, value){
   return "EvilHacker001>>" + value;
});
```

**Update**:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).val(function (i, value) {
            return value + '>>';
        })
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hBcHS/

Or:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    $(this).val(function (i, value) {
        return value.replace(/\n(?!>)/g, '\n>>');
    })
})
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't explain it very well.  I want to prepend each newline.  There isn't anything written in the text area...the user will do that.  I'm just trying to give it a terminal feel.

Comment: Yup the keyup function worked like a charm.  If I wanted to say....change the color of the prepended text could I do this at the same time or should I do that after??  I would think after as the text doesn't quite exist in the DOM if I do it at the same time as applying  prepend text.

Comment: The first line will not be prepended, use `'>>' + value.replace(/\n(?!>)/g, '\n>>');` to prepend it.

Answer (score 1):

prepend() adds the specified mark-up into the object returned by the jQuery selector (in this case the textarea). A textarea can contain only text, no other child elements; therefore you're trying to create invalid html.

If you want to prepend new text into the textarea:

```
$('#mytextarea').val(
    function(i,val){
        return 'EvilHacker001>> ' + val;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
 $('#myTextarea').val(function(i, value){
   return value.split('\n').join('\nEvilHacker001>>');     
 });
```

You have to get the newline character `\n` and then split and join with `\nEvilHacker001>>`.

#### [Get in the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6V7E/)